# How to include file which containing API to Another File which also containing API in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have code for APIs, some of which are for getting data and some of which are for messaging. So I have separated them into two files, `data.js` and `msg.js`. Now I want to programmatically include `msg.js` in `data.js`. How can I do that?

Comment: Where is your code! what have u tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will help.

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 
var msg = require('./msg')(app);


//msg.js
module.exports = function(app){
    //.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to expose some functions in msg.js and treat msg.js as a module in data.js. In particular, in msg.js:

```
module.exports = {
   someFunctionToCall: function(){
       // content for that function
   }
}
```

and in data.js, simply:

```
var msg = require('./msg.js');
msg.someFunctionToCall();
```

Comment: By using your solution we can call function of msg.js. But I do not want this for that i tried following and it works..                                                             var express = require('express');
var app = express();                                                                                                           var msg = require('./msg')(app);     this line register my API present in msg.js. Using this we can separate out our API